# How do adhesive forces provide charge to materials?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that friction between two bodies helps charge them. How does, for example, a piece of scotch tape stuck on a wooden table (adhesive force), charge the scotch tape?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the adhesive force that charges the tape. It gets the charge when the tape is removed. The dissimilar insulating materials form covalent type electron sharing bonds when they are in contact, the violent separation that occurs when you peel the tape away makes the charges in the tape and the table. You don't notice the charge on the table because it is large in comparison to the tape although there are some ways you may be able to observe it. If you stick one piece of tape on top of another on the table, pull both off at the same time then separate them from each other you will see they are both charged and will repel each other.

This website linked below has a very thorough explanation and descriptions of demonstrations you can do.

[Sticky Electrostatics](http://amasci.com/emotor/sticky.html)

Comment: Thank you. I was really taken in when I performed that experiment, that led me to suspect transfer of electrons caused by adhesive forces.

Comment: I was very surprised when I learned about how electrons share bonds and can cause charges and components to 'stick' together so strongly. There are many other experiments and demonstrations you can perform; just do a search for static electric physics experiments at home. Have fun!